# Javascript callback vs promises in terms of security

Tags: javascript, security, web

Currently I am reading up on how promises solves many of the problems that callbacks has. However, many of them talks about how it solves callback hell and makes code look cleaner. The question I have is, from a security point of view, is promises more secured than callbacks? If so, how is promises more secured than callbacks?

Comment: There is no difference. I don't see any relevance to security.

Comment: Of course, cleaner code leads to better code in general, but there is nothing inherently more secure about the way callbacks or promises are processed.